# How to make a continuously looping news Ticker in java

Tags: java, swing, animation

I dont know about you, but I tried so hard on how to create a news ticker. I found approaches that would append what was off the screen on to the back side of it. This caused the animation to jump by a whole character. Then I found methods that would not loop until the text was completely off the screen. After asking a ton of questions on this I thought it would be nice if I just posted my final solution for all the people wondering how to make it. Here you go.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;



public class Scroll2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{ 
    private int x;
    private int x2;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private String textIV;
    private Color textColorIV;
    private Color bGColorIV;
    private Font f=(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD,34));
    Timer t;
    // TODO font size
    public Scroll2(String text, Color textColor, Color bGColor)
    {
        x=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        x2=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        y=0;
        textIV=text;
        this.setVisible(true);
        Timer refreshTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000/50, this);
        refreshTimer.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setFont(f);
          if ( x == Integer.MIN_VALUE ){
              width=g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(textIV);
                x = 0;
                y = (int) (getHeight()*.6);

            }
          if ( x2 == Integer.MIN_VALUE ){
                x2 = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(textIV);
            }
        g.setColor(bGColorIV);
        g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), (int)this.getBounds().getWidth(), (int)this.getBounds().getHeight());
        g.setColor(textColorIV);

        g.drawString(textIV, x, y);
        g.drawString(textIV, x2, y);

    }

     public void refresh ()
        {
            if(x>=(-width)&&x2!=Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                x=x-2;
                x2=x2-2;

            }
            if(x2<=-width&&x!=Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                x2=width;
            }
            if(x<-width&&x!=Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                x=width;
            }
            repaint();
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) `new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD,34)` would better be `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD,34)` for compile time checking. 3) `this.setVisible(true);` really only necessary for top level containers. 4) `(int)this.getBounds().getWidth()` would better be `this.getWidth()` 5) `Scroll2` should have a more descriptive name (e.g. `TextMarquee`) and should override `getPreferredSize()` to return a sensible width and height based on the font and text.

Comment: 6) Expanding on (4).. `g.setColor(bGColorIV); g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), (int)this.getBounds().getWidth(), (int)this.getBounds().getHeight());`  Hmmm..  in fact.  Get rid of both those lines and add this line to the constructor:  `this.setBackGround(bGColorIV);` - this will have the same effect, but is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the name is not final at all, Just was using it for testing purposes. Definitely some sloppy things in here. The way I am using this ticker is that it can be added to a GUI with the specified screen width and height percentage, so Im not sure if getPreferred size would make sense.

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense to base the text size off of the height of the panel?

Comment: `Maybe it would make more sense to base the text size off of the height of the panel?` - it works the other way. As has already been suggested you override the `getPreferredSize()` method. The size of a component is based on the custom painting of the component. Also, as has already previously been suggested the [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) is more flexible and provides more features for anyone looking for scrolling text.